# Tensorflow get variance of loss function values

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there any way to get variance(standard deviation) of [batch_size x 3] loss in tensor flow??

I have a loss function like (batch_size = 60) :

```
Lx = tf.sqrt(tf.square(tf.subtract(lossx, poses_x)))
```

and it has 3 dimension for each (print(Lx)):

```
Lx Tensor("Sqrt:0", shape=(60, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Now, I want to get variance of 60*3=180 numbers. This means, variance should be [1x1] size.

I tried to get variance using :

```
meanx, varx = tf.nn.moments(Lx, axes=[1])
```

However it gives (60x1) result, which mean it return variances of 3 parameters for each index.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all axes:

```
meanx, varx = tf.nn.moments(Lx, axes=[0, 1])
```